# Excel data to word automatically

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I want to excel data to word. But ı wrote the code that is not working.Actually it is working but when export data the more rows there are the more word files creating. Can I gather the words files a one word file? I Thank you for answers in advance.
Here is the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")
    sablon = "D:\***\****\Desktop\schedule.docx"
    For i = 2 To 4
        Set doc = wordapp.documents.Open(sablon)
        doc.bookmarks("name").Range.InsertAfter Cells(i, 1)
        doc.bookmarks("people").Range.InsertAfter Cells(i, 2)
        doc.bookmarks("house").Range.InsertAfter Cells(i, 3)
        doc.SaveAs2 "D:\***\****\Desktop\" & Cells(i, 1).Text
        doc.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try moving `Set doc = wordapp.documents.Open(sablon)` to before the loop and the Save and Close lines after the loop.   At the moment it will open, save and close the file on each iteration.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using mailmerge in Word?

Comment: It is not suitable for many possible case. I want to say It isn't  flexible when we use microsoft word for this.